# parsing of string into json in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

here is my code..in android 
String

```
result[{"Submitted_Date_Time":"12\/3\/2012","City":"","Issue_Category":"Graffity","OnProgress_Date_Time":"","id":"000000000000000","area":"SH 55","State":"  ","Issue_Description":" ","Closed_Date_Time":"","imagepath":"android.graphics.Bitmap@40d55cd8","Latitude":"23.71","Longitude":"72.04","Issue_Status":"Closed","LandMark":" "}]
```

and i try to convert it in to json array and when i want to retrive json object from json array it gives me `nullpointer exception...`

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(1);
```

plz help me.. thnkx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

first your json String if it's contain `"result"` then it is not valid you can check it here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

to make valid json string just use String.replace as:

```
String finaljson=result.replace("result", "");
```

now JSON String is valid you can parse it as:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(finaljson);
for (int i = 0 ; i < jarray.length() ; i++) {
 JSONObject jsonobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
  // get value from json object here 
    String str_City=jsonobj.getString("City");
    ///....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Json array contains only **one** entry, the index is **0**

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(0);
```

To handle it right, access the json array using a `for` loop

```
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i = 0 ; i < jarray.length() ; i++) {
     JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
     .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your below code line it will solve your problem.

```
JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(0);
```

or you can write below code instead of your above code line if object is more than one.

```
for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```